# Internal Server Error when rewriting two different things

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite both the pages on my website and the blog seperately.
I receive a 500 Internal Server Error on the blog page when the other one exists.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

Rewrite Rule 1:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Rewrite Rule 2:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?title=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Read error.log from your server

Comment: Is `RewriteRule` #2 supposed to be affected by either of the `RewriteCond`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a weird thing about PATH_INFO. I'm guessing that the php extension rule is looping because of the blog request. The condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

is resulting to **true** when you have a request like this:

```
/blog/blah-title/
```

because the `blog.php` file exists, the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is actually checking PATH_INFO. Which means it's actually going to try:

```
/blog.php/blah-title/
```

in which case `-f` *is true*.

Try changing the condition to be more direct:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```

which doesn't do any sort of PATH_INFO matching like `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will.

Answer (score 0):

I this that there is syntax error in regexp

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([\-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?title=$1 [L,NC]
#                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ blog.php?title=$1 [L,NC]
```